# c - declaration after statment , gcc 4.5 vs visual c 2005

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, gcc

Following code does compile in gcc 4.5 but it is not being compiled in visual c 2005.

```
int main()
{
    int len;
    len = 32;
    char buff[len];

    return 0;
}
```

I know that i am declaring array after statment, which is against ANSI C rules.

But why GCC does not give any error or warning, and in visual c, it gives error like,

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
```

any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Always invoke gcc with options `-W -Wall -pedantic`, you will presumably see a lot more information on deviations from the various standards. Combine with with a dose of `-std=...` to use/allow compiler extensions.

Comment: @Kerrek SB.. Thanks for reply.. after using -pedantic, i am getting the warning from GCC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C code is not C90 compliant. `gcc -pedantic` will warn about this.

```
~/tmp$ gcc -pedantic a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘buff’
a.c:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
~/tmp$
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2005 compiler cannot handle dynamic array allocation. Try `char buff[32]`, it will work. It is a limitation of VS 2005.

Comment: It is a limitation of C89, which VS2005/08/10 tends to adhere to.